# Distorted UI in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

UI in my android emulator looks distorted.I tried different recommended values for `Screen Size` and `Monitor dpi`but no luck. With changing values emulator size changes but UI remains distorted.

[image]

**Details:**
Android API level : 10
Eclipse version : Helios (Build id 20090920-1017)
OS : Windows 7
Screen resolution : 1366 * 768

What are the other settings that I can apply?

Thanks!

Comment: its because your screen resolution is bigger than the size of emulator itself. Try reducing the size of your screen resolution.

Comment: @Dave : I did tried 1024*76 but still it is same. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Dave: But it looks bit better. How to find out emulators resolutoin?

Comment: Select your emulator using the AVD manager & click `edit` to see & change the properties of your emulator. I have shown the config I have for my emulator. try those parameters & see if thats what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a snapshot of my config using the AVD manager. Try to replicate these please and try.[image]

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: I checked for the `built-in` option for `Resolution` Which has some of standard resolutions. mine is `WVGA800`

Comment: Thank you Dave. I realized that scale shoule be around .77 to get good UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your emulator from avd manager.... While starting it, check the checkbox at launch option (to real size). give it value 6 or 7 as depending on your screen size.. and then it would work.

Hope that helps